# PySpark : How we select the dataframe which takes the highest values ​by Matricule?

Tags: arrays, dataframe, pyspark

I would like to select the dataframe which takes the highest values ​​by Matricule. For exemple in this table.

| Matricule | Count | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MA12 | A101 | 25 |
| MA12 | K215 | 25 |
| MA12 | C231 | 70 |
| MA12 | G348 | 70 |
| MA12 | B401 | 70 |
| MA12 | E291 | 70 |
| MA20 | D34 | 16 |
| MA20 | A45 | 16 |
| MA20 | A40 | 15 |
| MA20 | G16 | 18 |
| MA20 | K26 | 18 |

we obtain This table :

| Matricule | Count | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MA12 | C231 | 70 |
| MA12 | G348 | 70 |
| MA12 | B401 | 70 |
| MA12 | E291 | 70 |
| MA20 | G16 | 18 |
| MA20 | K26 | 18 |

Please can we help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I used to solve your problem is to create a `maxValue` column with Function Max and partition over `Matricule` column.

You can find the code below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

(df
  .withColumn('maxValue', F.max(F.col('Value')).over(W.partitionBy(F.col('Matricule'))))
  .filter(F.col('Value') == F.col('maxValue'))
  .drop('maxValue')
)
```